# Do summoned creatures get stronger as I level up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Do the creatures I summon—like the flame atronach—get stronger when I level up, or do they remain the same regardless of my level or the level of my enemies?

Comment: I suggest adding tags 'conjuration' and 'summoning' if someone with high enough reputation is able.

Comment: Those aren't useful tags, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok. I was suggesting because I noticed we have some tags of similar specificity, such as 'zerg'.

Comment: If nothing else, their magical (spell) attacks *don't* scale. Not sure about their health.

Comment: It's "atronach", not "astronach"

Comment: Ok I corrected that spelling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**, the other answer is wrong.  The summoned creatures from conjuration are not based on the caster level at all.

All summoned creatures have the same stats (health, damage, etc) regardless of what level you summon them at.  The only thing that improves the strength of the summoned creature is the Elemental Potency perk, which boosts all your atronach summons.

If you want a stronger summon, use a higher level spell (such as storm atronach).